# How can I efficiently convert a list of object ADto to a list of object BVo? Both objects have the same property values

Tags: java, list, dto, transformer-model

I have one class:

```
public class ADto
{
    private double c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
}
```

and another class

```
public class BVo
{
    private double c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
}
```

I have a list of BVo:

```
List<BVo> vo;
```

that I need to utilize a transformer to transform into a list of Dto's

```
List<ADto> dto;
```

This list of ADtos will then be put into a wrapper DTO and returned from my endpoint.

Is there an easy way to efficiently do this? Efficiency is key in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If by most efficient, you mean the fastest way. Then what you should do is to create a constructor in your `BVo` accepting `c`, `d`, `e`, and map it to its attributes.

```
public class BVo
{
    private double c;
    private String d;
    private String e;

    public BVo(double c, String d, String e)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }
}
```

After that, transform your initial list to new list using:

```
public List<BVo> convert(List<ADto> list)
{
    List<BVo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ADto item : list)
    {
        result.add(new BVo(item.getC(), item.getD(), item.getE()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would the for each be more efficient than your previous stream implementation?

Comment: @MichaelSmith Here nothing is a reasonable fast implementation stream or loop

Comment: yeah, im not super pleased with the task, its flawed imo @User - Upvote don't say Thanks

Comment: I've never benchmarked it myself, but I've read that using streams might get slower up to 30% than a simple for-loop. So if you really care about performance that much, it might give you the edge you need. If you have a really large amount of items, separating a list into smaller ones and processing them in parallel might help, but it also depends on the hardware. If you have a single-core processor, trying to run something in parallel is just unnecessary overhead and will be slower than the sequential processing.

Comment: @msmolcic thinking back I think I have heard something similar. Thanks for the comment.